# Unable to use ChromeDriver in WebDriver 3.13.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use `Selenium WebDriver 3.12.0` in a project with ChromeDriver. I try to update to version 3.13.0, but I get error message, unable to resolve following imports.

> import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
>
> import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

These are resolved in 3.12.0 and working properly. I use these dependencies in `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${ver.webdriver}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>${ver.webdriver}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>${ver.webdriver}</version>
</dependency>
```

Error message:

> Error:(2, 27) java: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace please

Comment: @DebanjanB : Code is working properly with version 3.12, no changes in code, I just try to upgrade version.

Comment: I tried the given imports with 3.13 and its working for me. What is the value of {ver.webdriver}?

Comment: @ShivamMishra : It is 3.13.0 now and it was 3.12.0.